# DHCP & bootpc ACL

Tags: acl

Could anyone help me with a simple explanation for the below ACL and what does have to do with DHCP server and IP address requests coming from hosts...

```
access-list 112 permit udp any eq bootpc any eq bootps
```

Thanks,
Ethem

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
access-list 112 permit udp any eq bootpc any eq bootps
```

Whatever interface this is attached to is permitting any upd bootp client requests destined for any bootp server.

So if a client on that interface sends a bootp request it will be forwarded to a bootp server.

Comment: It is there to allow client DHCP requests across the interface.  While they do different things, BOOTP and DHCP both use udp ports 67 and 68.

Answer (score 0):

The ACL is going to catch layer 3 stuff.  DHCP happens largely at Layer 2 (link layer).  You will often see `ip helper-address <DHCP SRVR ADD>` on the LAN/subnet interface directing DHCP request on to a remote server.

That ACL line is in there probably becuase there is an overall ACL on that interface and they had to add that line to allow the DHCP request to reach the remote server (to bypass the explicit `deny` at the end of the ACL).